# IIOP1002: Principal propagation: Cannot find principal information in subject]]

Tags: java, glassfish, single-sign-on, payara, waffle

I have [Waffle SSO filter](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/master/Docs/ServletSingleSignOnSecurityFilter.md) working perfectly fine , but our server logs are now totally filled with lines like below :

```
[2021-05-18T08:54:24.525+0100] [Payara 5.2021.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security] [tid: _ThreadID=115 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1621324464525] [levelValue: 1000] [[

  IIOP1002: Principal propagation: Cannot find principal information in subject]]
```

**So my question is, how to get rid of these logs ?**

Here are some other details :

AppServer -  Payara  5

Waffle SSO type - Filter based (version 2.3.0)

OS : Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that this may not be the best solution , but just a workaround !**

Okay, in the end only way to shut that logging was to comment the piece of line that did the logging :) . For this to happen , I had to recompile the **`SecurityMechanismSelector`** (present at C:\Payara\glassfish\modules\ejb.security.jar) , and comment the line :

[image]

You can find the source for **`SecurityMechanismSelector`** from [here](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/master/appserver/security/ejb.security/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/iiop/security/SecurityMechanismSelector.java) . Once the line has been commented and everything is compiled well in your IDE, you’ll need to put the class file back into jar and replace the original jar (present at C:\Payara\glassfish\modules) with newly compiled one .

Make sure , you remove the cache from the JEE server :

1. Stop the server
2. Delete all the files present at following location :

   ```
   C:\Payara\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache
   ```